# IndexError: pop index out of range (python)

Tags: python, sorting, merge

I wrote the following merge sort code:

```
def merge_sort(self,a):

    #console.log(len(a))
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a
    left = []
    right = []
    result = []
    middle = int(len(a)/2)
    print middle

    left = a[:middle] #set left equal to the first half of a
    right = a[middle:] #set right equal to the second half of a
    print left
    print right

    left = self.merge_sort(left)
    right = self.merge_sort(right)
    result = self.merge(left, right)

    return result
```

And then merging code:

```
def merge(self, left, right):
    result = []
    while len(left) > 0 or len(right) > 0:

        if len(left) > 0 and len(right) > 0:
            if left[0] <= right[0]:
                result.append(left[0])
                left = left.pop(1)    #remove the first element from left

        elif len(left) > 0:
            result.append(left[0])
            left = left.pop(1)    #remove the first element from left

        elif len(right) > 0:
            result.append(right[0])
            right = right.pop(1)  #remove the first element from right

        else:
            result.append(right[0])
            right = right.pop(1)
    return result
```

I send it the array:
    a = [12,0,232]

And I get the following outputs (different iterations) and at the last output I get the error, Please help I don't understand exactly why the error is there thank you!:

(1
[12]
[0, 232])
(1
[0]
[232])

Traceback (most recent call last):
...\Sort_Class.py", line 116, in merge
    left = left.pop(1)    #remove the first element from left
IndexError: pop index out of range

Comment: If `left` is shorter than 2 items, then you'll get this error.

Answer (score 3):

There are problems with your code, for example in this selection they are all present:

```
result.append(left[0])
left = left.pop(1)
```

This should be:

```
result.append(left.pop(0))
```

The problems are:

1. Python lists use 0-based indexing so `left[0]` is the first element of a list not `left[1]` so `left.pop(0)` pops the first element while `left.pop(1)` pops the second element
2. `left.pop(1)` returns the element popped not the list as it mutates the list. `left = left.pop(1)` wouldn't make much sense here.
3. one doesn't need to both fetch the first element by `left[0]` and then pop it `left.pop(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `.pop()` does what you think it does.  For example, this line:

```
left = left.pop(1)    #remove the first element from left
```

doesn't remove the "first" (i.e. zeroth) element from `left`.  `.pop(1)` is the second element:

```
>>> a = [10,20,30,40]
>>> a.pop(1)
20
>>> a
[10, 30, 40]
```

and moreover, if you set `a = a.pop(1)`, then `a` is no longer a list, but a number:

```
>>> a = [10,20,30,40]
>>> a = a.pop(1)
>>> a
20
```

which won't work either.  You can replace these with `del left[0]` or `left = left[1:]` or simply `result.append(left.pop(0))` as noted in an answer just posted. :^)  Fixing that reveals another problem, though: your code gets caught in an infinite loop due to the logic here:

```
    if len(left) > 0 and len(right) > 0:
        if left[0] <= right[0]:
```

If `left[0] > right[0]`, then no branch is taken, nothing happens to either `left` or `right`, and you're trapped.  If you tweak this to add a right-branch behaviour for this case, your code seems to work:

```
>>> import random
>>> def check():
...     for length in range(1, 10):
...         for trial in range(10000):
...             v = [random.randrange(-10, 10) for i in range(length)]
...             assert merge_sort(v) == sorted(v)
...     return True
... 
>>> check()
True
```